# Output off-state is too high

Tags: digital-logic, power-electronics

I'm currently working with a robot controller that has inputs and outputs. The output in on-state should give me 24V, which it does and is ok, but the off-state gives me 1.6V, which affects everyone that designs something, thinking it gives 0V.

I can't open the controller to see if there's something wrong, so if you could give me an external solution it would be great.

I tried using Zener diodes and it worked, but I wonder if there's a better solution.

Comment: What are your specifications for logic high voltage, logic low voltage and output current?

Comment: The controller surely has a manual? Otherwise no one can design anything with it. Also the voltage may depend on how you measure it. So with what and how you measure it?

Comment: Is that a low-impedance 1.6v? (i.e: you can draw current / things remain semi-powered), or is it problematic from a logic level point of view? (i.e: you're still seeing a 1, not a 0)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how simple you want this to be but here's a circuit that should take your controller's output and bring the logic low down to a few millivolts while keeping the logic high near 24 V. It uses a TL431 to sense when the input voltage is around 2.5 V and switch a sort of totem-pole output which should give at least 50 mA high or low drive.

[image: 24V logic output]
Note: I forgot to change Q3 to a 2N4401 like the others. Most general purpose transistors should work in this circuit, such as 2N3904 NPNs and 2N3906 for the PNP.

Answer (score 0):

Put a 3V source like on schematic below so its positive terminal creates a Gnd rail for your logic circuits. Now the 1.6V from your robot controller is far away below Gnd.

You can create 3V from 24V source using DC/DC converter.
Or supply the robot controller with two sources connected in series (3V+21V) and their middle point is Gnd.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKqGd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Won't your approach cause the high level output to be degraded from 24V to effectively 21V? I think you simply moved the problem from one signal level to the other.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson For NPN/N-ch logic the 21V is more then enough. For PNP/P-ch there is an option to use another 3V on high-side.